# Annotate Unit test c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

Is there any method of annotating a unit test to link it to the method that it's testing in C#?
There seems to be at least one naming convention... however I'd prefer it if I could quickly see which method was under test and ideally be able jump to to that method from within Visual Studio.

For example if I had a class:

```
class Numbers
{
   public static int SumTwoNumbers(int a, int b){...}
}
```

then a test class

```
class NumbersTests
{
   private void TestSumTwoNumbers() {...}
}
```

I'm wondering if there's some way of annotating the test class like:

```
[TestClass: Numbers]
class NumbersTests
{
     [TestMethod: Numbers.SumTwoNumbers]
     private void TestSumTwoNumbers() {...}
}
```

Comment: There's a [TestCategory] attribute. You could always use reflection to extract the associations.

Comment: Isn't the answer simply to organise your unit test classes the same as your actual classes? I.e. class `X` has a corresponding unit test class `XTest`, etc. then group the methods using `#region`

Comment: @Liam, `#region`? People still use those?!?? How very last decade.

Comment: You could create your own attribute classes. I can't see what use they'd be though, to be honest. To go to the method, select it and hit F12.

Comment: You can set the cursor to a method's name in the test code, and then press F12.

Comment: I'm aware of this thanks... it was more just to unify the location of the method.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Just do this:

```
[Test]
class NumbersTests
{
     Numbers numbers = null; //Double click on Numbers and press Alt-F12, the class will appear below it.
     private void TestSumTwoNumbers() {...}
}
```

Alt-F12 is a new feature that will let you see other code in place without leaving the file you are in. That will let you look over the code you are testing from your test class and will do exactly what you are looking for without having to write additional code to do so.

Edit: As you can see in the image using Alt-F12 will link you back to the code you are wanting to see (in place), which you can scroll through, make changes, etc as though you are on that page.

Comment: Can you please add comments indicating why this solution meets the needs of the asker?

Comment: The OP thanked the suggestions in the comments for the answer, but this is not what he is looking for.

Comment: It's actually exactly what he asked for. He wants to be able to see the code in the method he's testing from inside of Visual Studio. The IDE already does this and there's no need to link them together through code just to jump back and fourth between the two.

Comment: Might be OP's only option. Not deserved of the negativity.